# Android SQLite onUpgrade(), create new table

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, helper

In the method onUpgrade() of the Helper class, I added a new table. 
Unfortunately, the logcat tells me a syntax error "ADD COLUMN".

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {  
          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE denze  ADD COLUMN field1 TEXT," +
                "ADD COLUMN field2 TEXT," +
                "ADD COLUMN field3 TEXT," +
                "ADD COLUMN field4 TEXT");  

     }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not legal SQL.  You need an "[ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)" query.

You haven't given much info about what the old table looks like but if you just replace "CREATE" with "ALTER" it might just work.

... and, btw, you don't need to check that `newVersion` is newer than `oldVersion`.  It always will be.  There's an `onDowngrade` method that will be called if `newVersion` is smaller.